# Refresh ListView not working

Tags: android, listview

I've some database that i update with a service, and i want to update my listView on resume, or refresh it from time to time with the new data in it, but it's not working.

Here is my code (the code in comment is not working and sometimes make the app crash)

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    taskLiteApplication = ((TaskLiteApplication)getApplicationContext());

    listGroupTask = taskLiteApplication.getCtrlGroupTask().getListGroupTaskToDoAndToReview(taskLiteApplication.getUser());

    Log.d(TAG, "nbtask to do an to review from DB :"+listGroupTask.size());

    if(listGroupTask.size() > 0) {

        setContentView(R.layout.to_do_layout);
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewGroupTaskToDoToDo);

        //set adapter
        groupTaskToDoBaseAdapter = new GroupTaskToDoBaseAdapter(this, listGroupTask);

        lv.setAdapter(groupTaskToDoBaseAdapter);

    } else {
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("No tasks to do found!");
        setContentView(textView);
    }
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //listGroupTask = taskLiteApplication.getCtrlGroupTask().getListGroupTaskToDoAndToReview(taskLiteApplication.getUser());
    //groupTaskToDoBaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Log.d(TAG, "on resume");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly are your trying here:

```
listGroupTask = taskLiteApplication.getCtrlGroupTask().getListGroupTaskToDoAndToReview(taskLiteApplication.getUser());
```

Do you want a completely new set of data for your ListView. If so then implement some methods in your Adapter like add/remove/delete/replaceData and so on and after that call the

```
groupTaskToDoBaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Some data have been modified in the database and i want to update the listView with those data. So may be the method replaceData() on the Adapter i guess.

Comment: When i try to implements methods in my BaseAdapter i don't get the replaceData() one ?

Comment: You have implemented your own Adapter I guess. For example you extended from ArrayAdapter. There you have lets say an ArrayList containing all the data. So all you have to is to write a method that manipulates the ArrayList.

Comment: yes i've implemented my own one, it's was pretty easy but i didn't have though of that, thanks for your help!